# How to add SqlParameters in a loop?

Tags: c#, sql-server-2008, ado.net

I want to remove manual escaping from my code. Instead of this I want to use SqlParameter object.

```
foreach (ThreadPost post in ThreadPosts)
{
     string newMessage = Clean(post.Message);
     string oldMessage = post.Message;

     // escape ' character for prevent errors in SQL script
     // I want to pass newMessage and oldMessage as an SqlParameters to prevent unexpected changes, but how it could be done based on the code bellow???
     newMessage = newMessage.Replace("'", "''");
     oldMessage = oldMessage.Replace("'", "''");

     cmdText += string.Format("INSERT INTO ThreadCleanup VALUES ({0}, {1}, '{2}', '{3}')",
          post.ID.ToString(),
          "NULL",
          oldMessage,
          newMessage);
     }
}
if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(cmdText))
{
     using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(CONNSTR))
     {
          con.Open();
          SqlTransaction tran = con.BeginTransaction(IsolationLevel.ReadUncommitted);
          try
          {
              using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(cmdText, con, tran))
              {
                 cmd.ExecuteNonQuery(); // updated records
              }
              tran.Commit();
          }
          catch (SqlException ex)
          {
              tran.Rollback();
          }
          con.Close();
     }
}
```

Comment: [What have you tried](http://whathaveyoutried.com)? Please explain where you are stuck.

Comment: I want to not doing Replace("'", "''"). Instead of this I want use SqlParameters for adding newMessage and oldMessage to command.

Comment: Yes, I understand what you _want_. I am asking what did you **try**.

Comment: I don't know from what to start, because I'm not sure that it could be done in a loop as in example...

Comment: Did you try without a loop first? Do that, then see what can be abstracted out to a loop.

Comment: I'm doing this in a loop because I want to run multiple updates in a single query - so I'm building my command first - and then run it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it roughly the same way that you do now - by formatting an `insert` in a loop, but instead of using one insert per the new/old pair, use one statement for all pairs. You should use column names explicitly to avoid relying on the column order in the table (a big no-no in production) and to avoid creating the second parameter in a loop, even though you always send a `NULL` to it.

```
var cmdText = new StringBuilder("INSERT INTO ThreadCleanup (id,oldMessage,newMessage) VALUES ");
var args = new List<Tuple<long,string,string>>();
foreach (ThreadPost post in ThreadPosts) {
     int cnt = args.Count();
     if (cnt != 0) {
         cmdText.Append(",");
     }
     cmdText.AppendFormat("(@id{0}, @old{0}, @new{0})", cnt);
     args.Add(new Tuple<long,string,string>(post.ID, post.Message, Clean(post.Message)));
}
```

At this point, you have a SQL string that looks like this:

```
INSERT INTO ThreadCleanup (id,oldMessage,newMessage) VALUES
(@id0, @old0, @new0), (@id1, @old1, @new1), (@id2, @old2, @new2), ...
```

You also have a list of `Tuple<long,string,string>` for each of the parameters, so you can do this:

```
if (args.Count != 0) {
    using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(CONNSTR)) {
        con.Open();
        SqlTransaction tran = con.BeginTransaction(IsolationLevel.ReadUncommitted);
        try {
            using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(cmdText, con, tran)) {
               for (var i = 0 ; i != args.Count ; i++) {
                   cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@id"+i, args[i].Item1);
                   cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@old"+i, args[i].Item2);
                   cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@new"+i, args[i].Item3);
               }
               cmd.ExecuteNonQuery(); // updated records
            }
            tran.Commit();
        } catch (SqlException ex) {
            tran.Rollback();
        }
        con.Close();
    }
}
```

The advantage of doing it in one go is that you make a single round-trip to your database no matter how many records you must insert. Other than that, the solution follows the same pattern as your current one, so the performance should be comparable.

Answer (score 1):

Declare your Insert command outside foreach loop.
Then add SQLParameters to the command.

```
String cmdInsert= "INSERT INTO ThreadCleanup VALUES(@value1,@value2,@value3,@value4)"
        cmdInsert.Parameters.AddWithValue("@value1", System.Data.SqlDbType.VarChar);
        cmdInsert.Parameters.AddWithValue("@value2", System.Data.SqlDbType.VarChar);
        cmdInsert.Parameters.AddWithValue("@value3", System.Data.SqlDbType.VarChar);
        cmdInsert.Parameters.AddWithValue("@value4", System.Data.SqlDbType.VarChar);
```

Then inside foreach loop you assign the values.

```
foreach (ThreadPost post in ThreadPosts)
{
 string newMessage = Clean(post.Message);
 string oldMessage = post.Message;

 // escape ' character for prevent errors in SQL script
 // I want to pass newMessage and oldMessage as an SqlParameters to prevent unexpected changes, but how it could be done based on the code bellow???
 newMessage = newMessage.Replace("'", "''");
 oldMessage = oldMessage.Replace("'", "''");

cmdInsert.Parameters["@value1"].Value = post.ID.ToString();
cmdInsert.Parameters["@value2"].Value = DBNull.Value;
cmdInsert.Parameters["@value3"].Value = oldMessage;
cmdInsert.Parameters["@value4"].Value = newMessage;

}
```

Comment: it looks good, and how do you think - will it slow if I'll have 10k records?

Comment: This is the way to add value to SQLParameters dynamically. As your values will get changed every time, you can not add those using AddWithValue() . I think taken time will be aprroximately same as the running time of your foreach loop.

Answer (score 1):

type
 sqlcmd.Parameters.Clear();
before  sqlcmd.Parameters.AddWithValue ("@sample",sample);